# Drawing a graph for BFS that gives maximum length 4

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I just wanted to know what the question is asking about

So the question states:

Draw a graph, labelling the vertices with letters beginning at A, so that the queue in a Breath First Search of the graph beginning at vertex A would have a maximum length equal to 4.

So I know how a Breadth First Search works but what does it mean that it has a maximum length equal to 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link for your question:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/breadth_first_traversal.htm

There is the mention of the queue in that explanation and I believe it means the nodes or vertices in that queue cannot be more than four.

Comment: hmmm this is driving me crazy.. I still don't get it. Could you provide me with an illustrative example please

Comment: In that tutorialspoint link above, if you scroll down and read their explanation, they've illustrated the example with a queue. The statement "so that the queue in a Breath First Search of the graph beginning at vertex A would have a maximum length equal to 4" means that the number nodes or vertices in that queue cannot exceed more than four at any time. This is my interpretation.

Comment: oh. then if i just draw a vertex a and b that is connected wouldn't that be an answer?